# Interpolated values does not reflect the latest values in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

The elements of `dropzone1` array only reflect the initial top, left values, they do not reflect the latest top,left values.

In `draw()` function I push `top` & `left` values to `topLeft` array and finally push it to `dropzone1` array inside `move()` function, the initial `top` , `left` values are shown but it doesn't reflect the latest current `top` , `left` values.

```
export class FloorZoneComponent {

    urlFloorZoneIn: any;
    roomsFloorZoneIn: any;
    existingDroppedItemZoneIn: any[] = [];
    @Input() urlFloorZone;
    @Input() roomsFloorZone;
    @Input() currentBoxFloorZone;
    @Input() existingDroppedItem: any[] = [];
    dropzone1 = [];
    currentBox?: string = this.currentBoxFloorZone;
    mouse = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        down: false
      };
    will_draw = false;
    left;
    top;
    topLeft = [];

    @ViewChild('parentparent') parentparent; 
    
    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMousedown(event) {
        this.mouse.down = true;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
    onMouseup(event) {
        this.mouse.down = false;
    }

    documentMouseMove(e: MouseEvent) {
        // move logic
        if(!this.mouse.down) { return; }
      
        const container_rect = this.parentparent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.mouse.x = e.clientX - container_rect.left;
        this.mouse.y = e.clientY - container_rect.top;
        if(!this.will_draw) {
          requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
          this.will_draw = true;
        }

    }

    draw() {
        this.will_draw = false;
        const { width, height} = this.parentparent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const perc_x = this.mouse.x / width * 100;
        const perc_y = this.mouse.y / height * 100;
        // -5 to center (elem has its width set to 10%)
        console.log('left', (perc_x - 5) + '%');
        this.left = perc_x - 5;
        this.topLeft = []
        this.topLeft.push(this.left);
        // -5 to center (elem has its height set to 10%)
        console.log('top', (perc_y - 5) + '%');
        this.top = perc_y - 5;
        this.topLeft.push(this.top)
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.urlFloorZone && changes.urlFloorZone.currentValue) {
            this.urlFloorZoneIn = changes.urlFloorZone.currentValue;
        }
        if (changes.roomsFloorZone && changes.roomsFloorZone.currentValue) {
            this.roomsFloorZoneIn = changes.roomsFloorZone.currentValue
        }
        if(changes.existingDroppedItem && changes.existingDroppedItem.currentValue){
            this.existingDroppedItemZoneIn = changes.existingDroppedItem.currentValue;
        }        
    }


    move(box: string, toList: string[]): void { 
        box = this.currentBoxFloorZone;

        let objTemp:any = {
            pos:[]
          };
         
        objTemp.dis = this.currentBoxFloorZone;

        for(var i=0; i < this.topLeft.length; i++){
            objTemp.pos.push(this.topLeft[i]);
        }
        
        this.removeBox(box, this.dropzone1);
        toList.push(objTemp);
       
    }

    removeBox(item: string, list) {
            if (list.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
                list.splice(list.indexOf(item), 1);
            }
        
    }

    }
```

I call `move()` function and push name and `top` , `left` values to `dropzone1` array

```
<div (mousemove)="documentMouseMove($event)" #parentparent>

  <div class="dropzone" 
       (drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)">

  <div class="box"
       *ngFor="let existingZone of existingDroppedItemZoneIn">
    {{ existingZone.dis }}
    <span style="display: none">{{existingZone.left}}</span>
    <span style="display: none">{{existingZone.top}}</span>
   </div>

    <div class="box"
         *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" 
         (dragStart)="currentBox = box">
    {{ box.dis.dis }}
     <span style="display: none">{{box.pos[1]}}</span>
     <span style="display: none">{{box.pos[0]}}</span>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I am also able to log latest `top` , `left` values in console from `draw()`  function but the `*ngFor` elements do not reflect the latest one

#### Update 1

Adding [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyjtqw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Here in this link issue is in hello.component where I am assigning top,left values , in `draw()` and `move()` function.

For now I have provided box values from static array in `app.component` which in turn gets pushed to `dropzone1` array present in hello.component where the issue is.

### Update 2

I think I have figured out the issue but how to resolve this if  someone could suggest.

So whenever a new box is dropped the `move()` function is called

```
(drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)"
```

from which `top` , `left` values are pushed to the box properties and interpolated to the view . Now from where the `top` , `left` values come in , they come from `topleft` array being created from `draw()` function.

So the initial `top`,`left` value gets interpolated .But when the same element is dragged again then only `draw()` function is called and `top` , `left` values are calculated but not get pushed, because `move()` function is only called when new element is dropped.

So how can I bind the interpolated data to the latest values of top,left being calculated from `draw()` function. Please suggest.

Comment: What needs to be corrected in assigning values to dropzone1 array, so that it reflects the latest values

Comment: Added the stackblitz link with actual issues

Comment: @halfer No I have raised different issues :) and in the previous I thought I had complicated as well the explanation but more over there I had requested (1) issue which I have not asked here, thanks

Comment: It is not a big issue but I am not able to resolve it, the issue is the latest values are not being reflected in the interpolated values

Comment: Best practice is to type your uninitialised input variables. This will help you in the long run on any medium or above sized project.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Thanks for the input but what fix is required to avoid this issue, if you could point what is causing this issue then it would be really helpful

Comment: @Enthu: Can you join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198091/enthu

Comment: @Enthu : With such along question and a working stackblitz, I am getting lost in what exactly is the problem. Can you put steps to replicate this issue and expected behavior.

Comment: @Shashank Vivek hi

Comment: @ShashankVivek , hi , so actually when a new element is dropped then move function is called and top, left values are assigned to interpolated variable

Comment: @ShashankVivek , and "move" function gets top,left value from "draw" function, so 2 functions are what we need to inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `move()` is called only when a block is moved from outside the **Grey area** but the `draw()` is called for all mouse movement.

You need to update the `currentBox` position when it is selected and moved around.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ehjnz?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```
  draw() {
    const movingBlockIndex = (this.dropzone1.indexOf(this.currentBox));
    if (movingBlockIndex > -1) {
      this.will_draw = false;
      const { width, height } = this.parentparent.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const perc_x = this.mouse.x / width * 100;
      const perc_y = this.mouse.y / height * 100;
      // -5 to center (elem has its width set to 10%)
      // console.log('left', (perc_x - 5) + '%');
      this.left = perc_x - 5;
      this.topLeft = []
      this.topLeft.push(this.left);
      // -5 to center (elem has its height set to 10%)
      // console.log('top', (perc_y - 5) + '%');
      this.top = perc_y - 5;
      this.topLeft.push(this.top)
      this.dropzone1[movingBlockIndex].pos[0] = (perc_x - 5);
      this.dropzone1[movingBlockIndex].pos[1] = (perc_y - 5);
    }
  }
```

Comment: hi,  this works once I have selected a box and dropped and then drag it by selecting it , the current values are updated , but there is a issue , after dropping a box when without clicking on any box I drag the mouse inside the grey area the top,left values of the current box also starts updating , any remedy for this , thanks

Comment: @Enthu : I think that can also be handled. Just make sure that the `this.currentBox` is set to empty when the drag is complete.  Try it once and update the code if you are unable to make it work. And next time when the drag starts, the value is set again

Comment: I didn't get where to set that empty but will try and have to do for the second ngFor as well  , I''ll make that working then I'll ask ,as also I have to handle the removal of the boxes from the grey area to outside from both the *ngFor